# Custom ExpandableListView is not working

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I created custom `ExpandableListView` but it does not expand when I click on it.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ExpandableListView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/exp_lv"
    ></ExpandableListView>
```

**group_items.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<TextView 
    android:layout_width="270sp"
    android:layout_height="30sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30sp"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    />

<CheckBox 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/chk"
    />
```

**child_items.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/child"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    />
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView 
    android:layout_width="120sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:id="@+id/dd"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dd"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:id="@+id/date"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**group.java**

```
package com.example.expandablelistview;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class group {

private String Name;
private boolean isSelected;
private ArrayList<child> Items;

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return isSelected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean isSelected) {
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
}

public ArrayList<child> getItems() {
    return Items;
}

public void setItems(ArrayList<child> items) {
    Items = items;
}
}
```

**child.java**

```
package com.example.expandablelistview;

public class child {

String child_title;
String dd;
String date;
public String getChild_title() {
    return child_title;
}
public void setChild_title(String child_title) {
    this.child_title = child_title;
}
public String getDd() {
    return dd;
}
public void setDd(String dd) {
    this.dd = dd;
}
public String getDate() {
    return date;
}
public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}
}
```

**MyBaseAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.expandablelistview;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{
Context context;
ArrayList<group> group_al;

public MyBaseAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<group> group_al) {
this.context=context;
this.group_al=group_al;
}
@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    ArrayList<child> chList = group_al.get(groupPosition).getItems();

    return chList.get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
     child ch = (child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_items, null);
        }
        TextView child = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child);
        TextView dd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dd);
        TextView date= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);

        child.setText(ch.getChild_title().toString());
        dd.setText(ch.getChild_title().toString());
        date.setText(ch.getChild_title().toString());

        return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    ArrayList<child> chList = group_al.get(groupPosition).getItems();

    return chList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {

    return group_al.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {

    return group_al.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {

    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    group gr = (group) getGroup(groupPosition);
    long group_id = getGroupId(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.group_items, null);
    }

    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(gr.getName());
    CheckBox chk=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chk);
    chk.setFocusable(false);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {

    return false;
}

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.expandablelistview;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private MyBaseAdapter ExpAdapter;
private ArrayList<group> ExpListItems;
private ExpandableListView ExpandList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ExpandList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_lv);
    ExpListItems = SetStandardGroups();
    ExpAdapter = new MyBaseAdapter(MainActivity.this, ExpListItems);
    ExpandList.setAdapter(ExpAdapter);
}

private ArrayList<group> SetStandardGroups() {

    ArrayList<group> list = new ArrayList<group>();
    group gru= new group();
    gru.setName("Tax 1");

    ArrayList<child> ch_list= new ArrayList<child>();
    child ch = new child();
    ch.setChild_title("Information of tax 1");
    ch.setDd("Due Date:");
    ch.setDate("22/02/2016");

    ch_list.add(ch);

gru.setItems(ch_list);
list.add(gru);

    return list;
}
}
```

When I run the application I can see the first row of `ExpandableListView` i.e. Tax1 with `CheckBox` beside it but when I click on the row then it does not expanded.

Please guys help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

to your checkbox

also remove from textView:

```
 android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Comment: just a minute i will check

Comment: I tried it but also ExpandableListView not expanded

Comment: u have to set it to your checkbox

Comment: ok it works nice but I meet the new problem dude... I take three diffrent TextView in child item And I want to set following parameters to it  `ch.setChild_title("Information of tax 1");`
    `ch.setDd("Due Date:");`
    `ch.setDate("22/02/2016");`   _But I can see_ **Information of tax 1**   _in all three textviews_

Comment: u are setting        child.setText(ch.getChild_title().toString());
        dd.setText(ch.getChild_title().toString());
        date.setText(ch.getChild_title().toString());  all textview the same data that is why

Comment: Thanks Dude You Saved My life.. Thank You Very Very much

Comment: I want to store the checked CheckBox value (only group_title and value of Date TextView ) to the database so, where I add clickListener on Checkbox

Answer (score 0):

**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="270sp"
    android:layout_height="30sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30sp"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    ****android:textIsSelectable="true"**// remove this line in group layout**
    />
<CheckBox 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/chk"
    />
```

**

Comment: ya @Zeeshan Khan I make changes but I face new problem  I take three diffrent TextView in child item And I want to set following parameters to it `ch.setChild_title("Information of tax 1");` `ch.setDd("Due Date:");` `ch.setDate("22/02/2016");` _But I can see_ **Information of tax 1** _in all three textviews_

Comment: You are getting same value in all child item textview change child.setText(ch.getChild_title().toString());
        dd.setText(ch.getDd().toString());
        date.setText(ch.getDate().toString());

Comment: I want to store the checked CheckBox value (only group_title and value of Date TextView ) to the database so, where I add clickListener on Checkbox

Comment: please post a new question for that

Answer (score 0):

```
In MybaseAdapter please change method like this

@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
                             ViewGroup parent) {
        child ch = (child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_items, null);
        }
        TextView child = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child);
        TextView dd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dd);
        TextView date= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);

        child.setText(ch.getChild_title().toString());
        dd.setText(ch.getDd().toString());
        date.setText(ch.getDate().toString());

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much I got the solution

Comment: I want to store the checked CheckBox value (only group_title and value of Date TextView ) to the database so, where I add clickListener on Checkbox

Answer (score 0):

When I add

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

to your checkbox and

```
 android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

to TextView *then It works great*
but now I want to store the checked CheckBox value (only group_title and value of Date TextView  ) to the database so, where I add clickListener on Checkbox